# jQuery datatables row selectpicker

Tags: jquery, datatables

The question is how to create selectpicker inside table. I have rest api where I get values into my table. But my table must have `selectpicker` insade it. I dont know how to manage this. The selectpicker contains value from rest api. 
This is where I wanna put selecpicker:

1. `{ "sCellType": "select", "sClass": "selectpicker","data":'<option>'+"status"+'</option>'}`

My jQuery code looks like:

```
function get_all(){
    $('#data_table_out_mix').dataTable( {
        "dom": '<"top"fi>rt<"bottom"lp><"clear">',
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,

         "ajax":{
             url:'/out_invo_all/'
         },

         "columns": [

             { "data": "invoice_number" },
             { "data": "customer" },
             { "data": "date" },
             { "data": "due_date" },
             { "data": "total_invoice_amount" },
             { "sCellType": "select", "sClass": "selectpicker","data":'<option>'+"status"+'</option>'},
             {"defaultContent": '<img style="cursor:pointer" class="img-responsive CloneRow" src="../static/izibizi/images/forms/icon_duplicate.png">'},
             {"defaultContent": '<img id = "obrisi" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#OutgoingInvo" style="cursor:pointer" class="img-responsive OutgoingInvo" src="../images/forms/icon_delete.png">'},

         ]

    });
}
```

If you culd give me some advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use dataTables [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) function to create dynamic elements.

```
"columns": [

         { "data": "invoice_number" },
         { "data": "customer" },
         { "data": "date" },
         { "data": "due_date" },
         { "data": "total_invoice_amount" },
         { "data": "arraySelect", render: function(val) {
             var options = '';
             for(var i=0; i<val.length; i++)
                 options += '<option>'+val[i]+'</option>';
             return '<select>'+options+'</select>';
         }},
         {"defaultContent": '<img style="cursor:pointer" class="img-responsive CloneRow" src="../static/izibizi/images/forms/icon_duplicate.png">'},
         {"defaultContent": '<img id = "obrisi" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#OutgoingInvo" style="cursor:pointer" class="img-responsive OutgoingInvo" src="../images/forms/icon_delete.png">'},

     ]
```

Comment: @marin - are you trying to utilize the selectpicker bootstrap plugin within your DataTables initialization?  That's what I'm doing, but when I initialize the search function on the DataTable, it wipes the selectpicker class off the select.  Have you run into that?